# Choose class methods when there is OOP delegation

Tags: java, uml, encapsulation, class-design, ooad

This is a simple scenario for understanding this problem about persons and their house.

`Person` can change color of their `House`

I created this UML diagram:

[image]

As shown in above diagram:

- A `Person` can change their house color. To show that, I use `changeHouseColor()` method in the class `Person`.
- In the `House` class `changeColor()` method is for changing its color attribute.

I would implement the above scenario using java code as shown below. Please note this code as pseudo code, so syntax can be wrong.

```java
class Person {
    private House house;

    Person(House house) {
        this.house = house;
    }

    public void changeHouseColor() {
        house.changeColor(); // Delegation call
    }
}
```

```java
class House {
    private String color;

    public string getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void changeColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

I want to know:

- To show that a person can change his house color, I used the `Person.changeHouseColor()` method.  Does adding this method violate encapsulation?
- If this method is not needed in `Person` class, then how to show that a person can change his house color?
- In OOAD is it not mandatory that the person's actions are included as methods in `person` class?

Comment: Rather than `person.getHouse().changeColor(color)`?

Comment: If you cannot access the `House` directly from the `Person` then this is acceptable.

Comment: `person.getHouse().changeColor(color)`
but this is not showing that the person class is doing the color change

Comment: is it not mandatory that person's actions include as methods in `person` class

Comment: Your association is wrong. That's an Extends relation. Use an open arrow or none / role names and dot notation.

Comment: A funny house you have that has a changeColor() operation. How that? Different illumination? Wouldn't work at daylight, I guess.

Comment: Why would you need that operation at all? If it's only changing the property you can as well make it a public attribute. It's anyway public. Any sprayer can come by and prove that true (although it's not legal).

Comment: IMHO it doesn't violate encapsulation, but it can violates sometimes the single responsibility principle.
There's no exact answer on your question because they highly dependent from a context where the classes are used.

It like to ask how reasonable to use these two words together without knowledge of whole sentence and a topic of the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short my answers are:

1. No, encapsulation is not violated.
2. The fact that the `Person` can change the color is already given by the Association.
3. The `Person`'s actions can involve calling its own Operations, but many other actions are possible.

Further Explanations:

**point 1:** Encapsulation in its formal description just says, you should not directly use the attributes of other Classes. It is completly Ok to call an Operation of another Class and it is Ok to offer an own Operation that delegates something to another Class. Whether it is good design depends on your specifc domain, as the other answers have suggested.

**point 2:** When a Class has access to instances of another Class, it can potentially use all of its public Features. In your example, there is an Assocation between `Person` and `House`. Therefore, `Person` can call `changeColor`, but is not required to do it. In a more complete model `House` could have many more Features and not all of them might be meant to be used by `Person`. In this case it is useful to define a client specific Interface, only containing the Features needed by the `Person` Class. The Association would then be directed to this Interface, which in turn gets realized by the `House` Class. The `Person` Class is still technically not required to use all the Features of the Interface. However, I would view an Association to an Interface as a strong indication of the modelers intent, that all Features get used eventually.

**point 3:** In OOAD Activity Diagrams are commonly used for *analysing* Use Cases. In this case the Actions are not connected to specific Classes and therefore no Operations are defined in this step.

In a complete *design* model, the Behavior of the `Person` Class would be specified somehow. It could be with an Activity. In this Activity there could be many Actions. One could be a `CallOperationAction`, that calls `changeColor`. This would be an explicit specification of how the `Person` Class uses the `House` Class. It could also call its own Operation `changeHouseColor`, which in turn could be specified with an Activity.

There are many other Actions defined in UML, like `ReadStructuralFeatureAction` or `CreateObjectAction`. They are not used very often, since it doesn't make much sense to model at this level of detail. However, I think it is helpful to know about them, to better understand how Operations and Actions are connected.

Comment: in point 2 
[[In this case it is useful to define a client specific Interface]]
can you explain this
is this interface for `Person` class

Comment: "In this case it is useful to define a client specific Interface, only containing the Features needed by the Person Class."

this means interface for `House` class am i right

Comment: @Susantha7: Yes, an Interface realized by the `House` Class and used, via an Association, by the `Person` Class. It would only have one Operation `changeColor()` and thus could be named `Colorable`.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario the two basic options are to either:

- add a `getHouse()` method to `Person`, which requires client code to observe this and use the interface of `House` appropriately, or
- as you have done, *hide the delegate* (`House`) with an extra method on `Person`.

This is a classic design trade-off discussed in Fowler's *Refactoring : improving the design of existing code* as the [**Hide Delegate**](https://refactoring.com/catalog/hideDelegate.html) refactoring. To answer your question, in addition to the documentation benefit you mention, hiding the delegate actually *increases* encapsulation:

> If the delegate changes its interface, changes propagate to all the clients of the server that use the delegate. I can remove this dependency by placing a simple delegating method on the server that hides the delegate. Then any changes I make to the delegate propagate only to the server and not to the clients.

Comment: is it not mandatory that person's actions include as methods in `person` class

Comment: what are the pros and cons ? any material available for further read

Comment: is this Chapter 8. Organizing Data - Replace Subclass with Fields

Answer (score 2):

In general there is nothing wrong in both `person.changeHouseColor(color)` and `person.getHouse().changeColor(color)`. What approach is better depends on your [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

We can say `person.getHouse().changeColor(color)` violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (LOD) or principle of least knowledge. The idea is to have knowledge only about "closely" related classes. Classes having an instance of `Person` should not depend on its internal structure and instead call only methods of the `Person`: `person.changeHouseColor(color)`.

This approach has both advantages and disadvantages. The main advantage is the ability to change the internal structure of classes (`Person` class) without reworking their clients.

It definitely does not violates the encapsulation paradigm. Restricting the direct access to some of object's components can be even treated as better encapsulation.

A disadvantage is the need to write many wrapper methods to propagate calls to delegates.

But if you want to express that only person can change change a `House` color than the model is not ideal probably. Because any class that has an access to a `House` instance can call `house.changeColor(color)` directly without even having a `Person` instance. And there will be a `House` instance at least in the method that creates it:

```
House house = new House(Color.WHITE);
Person person = new Person(house);
person.changeHouseColor(Color.ORANGE); //OK
house.changeColor(Color.WHITE); //should we allow it?
```

This aspect depends a lot on the domain. It's important to identify [Aggregates](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) in your domain.

Comment: I agree: LoD is another good argument against this design :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### In short

Fundamentally, there is no universal right or wrong to this question.  It all depends on the responsibilities that you want to give to your classes in their collaborations.  But in the majority of the cases, don't !

#### Pros - When to do this ?

If it's the sole responsibility if the `Person` to change the color, and nobody else should care about the `House`, then your design makes sense.  It has the the advantages of hiding the delegation as already nicely explained by [SDJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565166/3723423).

But this is not the sole way to distribute the responsibilities between the classes, and there are many reasons to leave the design more open, for example: 
What if the `Person` doesn't paint her house herself, but asks a `Painer` to do the job on her behalf? What if, hypothetically, the mayor of the village would have the power to decide on the change of color, and send his painters accross the village ?

#### Cons - avoid it if possible !

There is a big disadvantage in your design.  It has to do with the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html):

> A class should have only one reason to change

Adding `changeHouseColor` implies that `Person` has more than one reason to change: first it may change with the concept of Person itself.  But it might then also have to change as consequences of changes in `House`.   For example, if tomorrow, the interface of `House` evolves to require an additional thickness parameter for `changeColor`, not only would your `Person` implementation change (providing the additional parameter in the delegation call), but also the `Person` interface would have to change, so that the thickness is provided as well.  So a small change in `House` would propagate to all the class using `Person`. The hidden coupling can quickly become a **technical debt**.

If you start to replicate every method in every class that could remotely access it, you will further face a combinatorial explison in your interfaces, which would quickly freeze the evolution of any interface because of the risk of change propagation.

#### Conclusion

Separation of concerns should drive your design.  If the concept of `Person` is independent of the concept of `House`, do not couple them unnecessarily. Do this only if there is a strong need to do so (for example if the house is private and nobody has to know anything about it).

Also, in UML there is no need to add `changeHouseColor()` method to show that a person can change the colour of the house.  The simple association between `Person` and `House` shows that Person can invoke any public method of `House`.

If you provide a `getHouse()` in Person, or if you'd add a public `+myHouse` at the house end of the association, you would also communicate that other classes can access a `Person`'s `House`

Comment: [ The simple association between Person and House shows that Person can invoke any public method of House]

then person can invoke methods in the `House` class which 
can consider as behaviors of other classes(other classes associated with `House class`)

Comment: Preson can change house color using  `Preson .changeHouseColor()` method it's associated method in `House` class is `changeColor()`  .   

Termite can decrease house Strength using `Termite.decreaseHouseStrength()` method it's associated method in `House` class is `changeStength()`

Comment: according to you then `Person` class can access `changeStength()` method but person has nothing to do with `House` strength.  then how to prevent person class access `House.changeStength()`

Comment: @Susantha7 yes. The design should ensure that the behaviors of house are relevant, whoever invokes this method. The class should shape the collaboration and not the contrary.  This is a consequence of the principle of separation of concerns, and a core principle if you want to achieve maintainable software with low coupling. More here: http://c2.com/doc/oopsla89/paper.html

Comment: @Susantha7 and this is a reason more for not adding changeHouseColor to a person: in reality the responsibility to set the color belongs to the house and other entities could also invoke it. Also be careful with the analogies. In the real world the color of the house is defined not by the house but by the paint, and the paint can be put on the house by anyone having the will to paint, disposing of paint, and having access to the house regardless of legal rights on the object.